# If $E \| X_n \|_{L^p} < \infty$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty | F_n(t) - F(t) |^p dt = 0$ a.s.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

From

http://www.ams.org/journals/tpms/2007-75-00/S0094-9000-08-00716-3/S0094-9000-08-00716-3.pdf

I found the statement that:

> Consider $\xi_i$ is i.i.d. random variable in $R^1$ with distribution function $F(t)$;$X_n(t) = I_{(-\infty, t)}(\xi_n)-F(t)$; $F_n(t) = n^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^n I_{(-\infty, t)} (\xi_i)$.
>   If $E \| X_n \|_{L^p} < \infty$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty | F_n(t) - F(t) |^p dt = 0$ a.s.

In the article, the citation is 
M. Ledoux and M. Talagrand, Probability in Banach Spaces.

But I don't have access; is it possible to get a gist of the proof? Perhaps departing from Glivenko-Cantelli?

I am trying to prove that $F_n \to F$ in $L^2$ a.s. for myself.